# htaccess causing server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, internal-server-error

I have a Zend Framework application with a `.htaccess` file in the root directory, directing all traffic to the `/public` directory, where `index.php` resides.

This is the contents of the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(upload|img|js|css|less)/.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(jpg|png|mp3))$ /public/upload%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

;RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
;RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

As you can see, there are two commented out lines.

The section, supposedly directing traffic to `/public`, and which works on my local servers and my shared host, seems to fail miserably on my client's server.

So, with the two lines commented out, when I type the site's address in the browser, I get a directory listing. When I append `/public` to the address, I'm taken to `/public/index.php`, as expected, but since the request wasn't redirected correctly, neither are the ones to the JS and CSS files.

When I uncomment the lines, I get a 500 internal server error (`index.php` is not reached at all).

The other rewrites work correctly (at least as far as I can tell).

Any ideas why this would happen and how to correct this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To my knowledge, "#" is the only permitted comment character in configuration (or .htaccess) files, therefore your two "commented" lines aren't, actually.

From the [Apache Server 2.x documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html):

`Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored. Comments may not be included on a line after a configuration directive.`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I actually ERASED the "commented out: lines in my .htaccess, and only left them here for reference regarding what was removed. I didn't know the semicolon was an invalid comment character though ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself a lot of grief and do the following:

1. Set the document root to the `public` directory.
2. Set the [rewrite rules in the VirtualHost entry](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/project.structure.html#rewriting-inside-a-virtualhost) or use the standard [Zend Framework rewrite rules](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/project.structure.html#rewriting-within-a-htaccess-file) in a `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory.

Ok, given your shared hosting constraints, try this one out...

1. Place all the `public` files into your document root including the `.htaccess` file mentioned in step #2 above
2. Place the rest of the folders (ie `application`, `library`) anywhere in the filesystem, preferably outside the web document root. An example might be `/home/user/apps/my-app-name/`
3. Modify the `index.php` file with the new `APPLICATION_PATH`, eg

   ```
   // Define path to application directory
   defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
       || define('APPLICATION_PATH', 'home/user/apps/my-app-name/application');
   ```

Now everything should "just work" and your site won't be accessed with the word "public" in the URL.

Comment: I can't. This is the point. It's a shared host, I have no access to vhosts.conf and I need to rely on mod-rewrite to direct the traffic from the root directory to /public. Were it so easy, I'd do it in the first place, without writing the custom .htaccess.

Comment: @mingos I've added another solution to your problem

Comment: Hmm... requires rewriting parts of the code (I have a public and a non-public `upload` folders, for instance)... but it's worth a try...

Comment: It *mostly* worked. In the end, I was unable to use this solution, but it was my client's server behaving oddly (the hosting company uses some custom-built version of Apache with really weird and ZF-unfriendly config, e.g. disallowing access to anything outside docroot, leaving my application directory unsecured), BUT! The client was annoyed with the hosting company as well and moved to a much, much better host :). Thanks for your help though.